# Access Claims data from JWT Auth Token in web api

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

```cs
string Accesstoken = "Token";
string key = "my_secret_key_12345"; //Secret key which will be used later during validation    
var issuer = "SiteURL";  //normally this will be your site URL    
var securityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key));
var credentials = new SigningCredentials(securityKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);
var jwt_token = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().ReadJwtToken(token);
string claims = string.Join(";", jwt_token.Claims);
```

The above code is reading my claim data from the token. I need to assign this claims to below params instead of Guid.Parse(authParams[0]) need to assign it from claims.TenantId something like this.

```cs
TenantId =  Guid.Parse(authParams[0]),
Env = authParams[1],
UserId = Guid.Parse(authParams[2]),
SessionId = Guid.Parse(authParams[3]),
EmployeeID = int.Parse(authParams[4]),
Language = language,
TimezoneOffset = timezoneOffset
```

Comment: Can you include more details in your question about the problem you're facing? After all, wouldn't it just be matter of iterating `jwt_token.Claims` until you find one with the type "TenantId", and then save the value?

Comment: I am not able to assign the data to my params above. I can Read the claims from token need help in assigning it. My Read Token returning this {
  "jti": "1109777c-2d71-4bea-91f3-bc3040d084a9",
  "TenantId": "8B6AAF27-CAB0-4D45-A22A-293A40C7983A",
  "Env": "IDB",
  "UserId": "77777777-7777-7777-7777-777777777777",
  "SessionId": "530c9d45-f371-4950-9fad-de0c6f409abf",
  "EmployeeID": "0",
  "exp": 1622085870,
  "iss": "URL",
  "aud": "URL"
}

Comment: Where does `authParams` come from? Why can't you assign the value from the appropriate claim in `jwt_token.Claims`? Please show your attempt to do this (as an edit to your question, not as a comment). In my mind it's simply `string tenantIdText = jwt-token.Claims.FirstOrDefault("TenantId")?.Value;`. Can you be more specific about why this isn't sufficient?

Comment: OK! I tried this way   TenantId = jwt_token.Claims.FirstOrDefault("TenantId")?.Value, but I am getting error as cannot convert from string to System.Func<System.Security.Claims.Claim,bool>

Comment: My bad. What about `string tenantIdText = jwt_token.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "TenantId")?.Value;` (sorry, on `ClaimsIdentity` there is a `.FindFirst(...)` method which I was thinking about, but of course you're dealing with `IEnumerable<Claims>` here instead, and my brain got mixed up). If that works, let me know and I'll add it as an answer.

Comment: Still no :( Also I forgot to tell you Tenant Id is a GUID so it is giving conversion error from string to GUID as well

Comment: You mean `Guid.Parse(tenantIdText)` doesn't work? Are you sure the value held by `tenantIdText` represents a GUID?

Comment: Yes it represent GUID. "TenantId": "8B6AAF27-CAB0-4D45-A22A-293A40C7983A",

Comment: There’s a lot of data in comments which I supposed to be in original post. Can you modify the post... especially the variable `authparams`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to retrieve the claim like this:

```
var jwt_token = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().ReadJwtToken(token);
var tenantIdClaim = jwt_token.Claims.SingleOrDefault(c => c.Type == "TenantId");
```

If the claim doesn't exist, `tenantIdClaim` will be `null`, so you should check this. Alternatively, you could use `.Single(c => c.Type == "TenantId")` which will throw an [`InvalidOperationException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.single?view=net-5.0) if the claim doesn't exist.

Then you can parse it and assign it to `TenantId`:

```
TenantId = Guid.Parse(tenantIdClaim.Value);
```

Note that `Guid.Parse` will throw a [`FormatException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.guid.parse?view=net-5.0) if `tenantIdClaim` doesn't hold a valid GUID. You could use [`TryParse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.guid.tryparse?view=net-5.0) instead if this is a concern for you. Examples are further down the linked documentation pag.e

Comment: @Llama Shouldn't it be `TenantId = Guid.Parse(tenantIdClaim.Value);` ?

Comment: @AkshayGaonkar Yes it should. Thanks! :)